# Change my input into an other format

Tags: java

I kindly ask for your help because I am stuck. I have input in this format:

6 <-- number of vertices

0 1 2 <-- vertices directly linked to vertex 0 by an edge

1 0 3 4

I need this in my program to be like this:

```
int[][] edges = {
   {0,1}, {0,2}, 
   {1,2}, {1,3}, 
   {2,5},
   {3,2}, {3,4},
   {5,4}
};
```

I got stuck, and think I might have to work with a list? This is what I had so far:

```
public class Part1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k = scanner.nextInt(); // number of vertices
        String[] input = new String[k];
        int[][] edges;
        String[] tokens = new String[k];
        int[] vertices = new int[k];
        int[] integers = new int[k];
        int p = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            vertices[i] = i;
            input[i] = scanner.nextLine();
            tokens = input[i].split("[\\s+]");
            integers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i].trim());
            for (int j = 0; j < integers.length - 1; j++) {
                edges[p][i] = integers[0];
                edges[p][2] = integers[j];
                p++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Why not use a collection? This could ease the handling with the array indices.

Comment: So, what you want to achive is to "connect" the different vertices? Say vertice 0 is connected to 1 and 2 and vertice 1 is connected to 2 and 3 etc?

Comment: You have not initialized your array `int[][] edges` and that would prevent your code from compiling if you try to use it.

Comment: Maroe, can you tell me how to use a collection? I'm not a 'programmer', but a student who has to do this assignment. My problem is that I know very little from java. 

Indeed I trie to connect the different vertices. It is given to me that I have to do this in this format.

Comment: Edalorzo, can you tell me how I can initialize something, I don't know how big the array should be for in advanced? Than must I use a list?

Comment: The answer below uses collection - so have a look onto that.

Answer (score 2):

I would ask you to consider representing your graph in a different way. The conventional way to represent a graph (and convenient way for many basic graph algorithms)  is Vector[], an array of lists declared like so.

```
Vector<Integer> graph = new Vector<Integer>[number_of_vertices];
```

Accessing graph[i] will return to you the Vector which contains the neighbours of vertex i. Hence, this data-structure lets you dynamically add edges efficiently as well as traverse the neighbours quickly. Some sample code to construct your graph:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  tokens = line.split(" ");
  int from = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
  for (int j = 1; j < tokens.length; j++) {
    graph[from].add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]));
  }
}
```

EDIT: See kant's response to workaround not being able to use generic arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually try handeling the vertices and edges in an other format. But I have more code I can use, and it uses the other format. I have to do a depth first search. I have the code for this given. Although I think you are right stating I should use an other format, I want to use the rest of the code that is given to me.

Comment: I tried your way. Now I have a problem already with the first line.
When using:
        Vector<Integer> graph = new Vector<Integer>[number_of_vertices];

I get the error:
generic array creation

Answer (score 1):

As I know java doesn't allow to use arrays of generic types. How about modifying example above this way:

```
Map<Integer,Vector<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<Integer, Vector<Integer>>();

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  tokens = line.split(" ");
  int from = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
  Vector<Integer> = v new Vector<Integer>();
  for (int j = 1; j < tokens.length; j++) {
    v.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]));
  }
  graph.put(from, v);

}
```

when you want to retreive value you write:

```
  Vector<Integer> v = graph.get(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question, because I never used the type 'Vector'. Is this like a list or an array? I get an error in the line where I use Vector<interger> which says "generic array creation". Do I need to import something to use this?

Comment: Vector is threadsafe array. You shouldn't create array of Vector<Integer>. It is not allowed. That's why i used Map in my example. To use collections you import java.util.*